# How to handle env value in _next/static/chunks

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

Hello i have some founding env value showed in next chunks when we called with process.env in index.js.

i used "next": "^10.2.3"

[image]

any suggestion how to hide it?

Comment: I assume somehow this is a client sided encryption? This should go on the server if you want to hide it.

Comment: Can you show how you are consuming those env variables?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar here
let cip = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', process.env.ENKEY, iv);

in .env
ENKEY=test123123123123123